# Fault string error while accessing web service in iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, soap, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am accessing xml web service in my iPhone application. But i am not able to get the appropriate data from the server. I am getting following error in connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method of NSURLConnection.

> soap:ServerServer
>   was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Following is my code :

```
NSString *deviceID = [OpenUDID value];

NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                     "<soap:Header>"
                     "<AuthHeader xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                     "<Username>admin</Username>"
                     "<Password>admin</Password>"
                     "</AuthHeader>"
                     "</soap:Header>"
                     "<soap:Body>"
                     "<WsGetAllDrugDetailsXML xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                     "<UserId>%d</UserId>"
                     "<IMEI>%@</IMEI>"
                     "</WsGetAllDrugDetailsXML>"
                     "</soap:Body>"
                     "</soap:Envelope>",[Appdelegate.UserID intValue],deviceID];


//---print it to the Debugger Console for verification---
NSLog(@"%@", soapMsg);

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:Appdelegate.wsURL];

//---set the various headers---
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/WsGetAllDrugDetailsXML" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

//---set the HTTP method and body---
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if (conn) {

    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

I'm not able to predict what is going wrong from my side. Or it is the error from server side that i'm not receiving the data.
Please help me.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Test your web-service using some soap client. You can check whether the problem is in web-service or your code..

Comment: you can test your wsdl in soapui or directly executing end point url in webbrowser to check whether your service is working or not. I am not familiar with xcode so cant help in ur client.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Content-Length` value is not correct:

The length must be in bytes. NSString's `length` method returns the number of UTF-16 code units.

You may fix it as follows:

```
NSData* bodyData = [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[req addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)[bodyData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPBody:bodyData];
```